Seeking Advice for Improving a Heavy-Duty Unidirectional Conveyor Drive Using a Car Battery (PWM-Driven, Low-Side Switch MOSFET (~60 A, 12 VDC)
I am developing a robust conveyor system powered by a 12 V car battery, which requires handling significant current. Our goal is to integrate a simple yet effective drive with adjustable speed control. My attempts with various low-side switch configurations have resulted in excessive heating, particularly at low RPMs and lower PWM duty cycles. While I am aware of methods to manage this heating, I am more inclined to optimize the electronic design first. I would appreciate any suggestions or feedback on how to enhance the efficiency of this design.
System Details:

Motor specifications: The system uses a brushed DC motor rated at 12
VDC and 500 W, equipped with a 26x reduction gear. Under no load, it
draws about 16 A, but the current can surge up to 50-60 A for
3-5 seconds depending on the load.
Control Method: The gate drive is controlled by a PWM signal from a
PLC, adjustable between 80 Hz and 800 Hz. I am considering the
IXDD604PI for the gate driver and using a DAMI160N100 MOSFET as the
switch.
Filtering: C1 (22 mF) is configured as a high-pass filter, and C2
(470 nF) serves as a low-pass filter.

Questions and Challenges:
I am uncertain about which parameters are critical on choosing appropriate diodes, capacitors, resistors. Any hints or guidance regarding this would be very helpful.
I also seek advice on selecting components for a snubber circuit to protect against voltage spikes and enhance overall system stability.
Attached below is the schematic of my described setup for reference. Your insights into how I can make this system more efficient and reliable would be greatly appreciated.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

What's the purpose of D1? Very strange.

Gate driver might make it unnecessary, but I've read recommendations about installing a Zener diode between the source and gate to protect against Vgs voltage overshooting, which could damage the MOSFET. Typically, Vgs is limited to 20 volts because higher voltages could oxidize the gate (or something like that). That's why I'm considering installing a Zener diode with a 15V breakdown voltage.

Fair enough, but why 2 kohm in series? It will just raise the impedance and make the clamping weak. I say skip it but place a 100 kohm one in parallel to ensure startup from zero.

Yes, indeed, that would make more sense. Thank you!

Generally, you need to select your MOSFET Rdson to be low enough to not overheat, given your available cooling situation and max running current. On top of that, it needs to withstand at least your max DC bus voltage + turn-off spike due to stray inductance and diode trr. Effectively, twice your max bus voltage is a good starting point. Your 4 mΩ MOSFET suggestion would burn 14 W at 60 A. Possible, but you need a decent heatsink for it. I would recommend you use several smaller ones instead. It would be possible to have an array of SMD MOSFETs with no heatsink. Compare the cost (and weight) of your heatsink versus MOSFETs.
For diode, similar story, current rating ideally 2x your peak current rating (probably at stall condition) and 2x your max DC bus voltage. You need it to be fast enough (trr low enough) to be say 1/100f where f is your switch frequency.
R? and C3 would ideally be selected from simulation with your switching frequency in question and tune to give reasonable damping without excessive power dissipation.

Thank you for sharing your expertise. We initially started with 8 parallel IRF3205 FETs, but they ended up energizing the heatsink. Considering SMD models would definitely be a better option. I now understand that parallel MOSFETs should theoretically result in a lower Rds(on) – thanks for highlighting that.
I don't have experience with electrical simulations, but we are considering installing a rheostat in place of R1 and possibly experimenting with a variable capacitor to find a better balance in the snubber circuit.
About the diodes: Should D3 be a Schottky diode?
Thank you!

@Mark The tab of IRF3205 is not electrically insulated. You need to use a thermal interface with electric isolation, for example mica or gap-pad. D3 would benefit slightly from a Schottky. Easier to parallel too if needed.

do you have any insights on selecting capacitors based on their ripple current ratings? I'm trying to understand the expected ripple currents at different parts of the circuit (C1/C2 vs. C3). For instance, in a previous setup with a purchased H-bridge drive, the manufacturer recommended adding a 22 mF capacitor in parallel with the drive terminals (like C1 /C2 in the schematic). I opted for a KEMET capacitor rated for a ripple current of 93 amps (really expensive), but I’m now wondering if that might be excessive. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot for your insight!

@Mark I would start by simulating the circuit, including loop inductance from your cable, battery ESR and ESL and capacitor ESR and ESL. From there, check for over/undershoot coming from zero into startup condition as well as stopping from max load. If your cables are long, you may destroy the MOSFET without sufficient capacitance (C1/C2). In SPICE, you can calculate the actual current ripple and then select a capacitor in real life which can withstand it.
